# MlKit vision returns different values on different phones

Tags: android, computer-vision, firebase-mlkit, tensorflow-lite, google-mlkit

MlVision enables users to access the eyeOpenProbability. Today I detected a strange behaviour:
When I run the exact same images on the same phone for several times, I always get the same values. But when I run these images on a different phone, using the exact same code, the values differ.

Does anybody know why?

Comment: The Face Detection API in ML Kit is backed by Google Play services, so there might be slightly different results if the devices in questions are running different versions of Google Play services. Could you check the versions?

Comment: @Chrisito You were right. The versions are slightly different. However I can't update Google Play Services on my old phone - It says it is the newest version. My old phone runs an older version of Android. Does Android limit the google play services updates for certain android versions?

Comment: Can you tell us the phone version and Google Play Services version? Also was the Services sideloaded or did it came preinstalled?